Anylogic: Using multiple Delay blocks in a row
Im trying to model a construction schedule in Anylogic. I want to represent all construction activities through delay blocks which are normal distributet.
My question now is: How can I set up multiple delay blocks for various construction activities which start at the same time, for example after another task is finished?
I will appreciate any help.
I tried using blocks such as the combine block but that didnt really work out.

It sounds like you do not yet understand how process models work, tbh. Do some more tutorials first and define what should be agents and what should be resources. Delay blocks work sequentially for the entities flowing through... You cannot change that.
